# Plot labels outside SpatialPolygons (R)

Tags: r, label, gis, polygon

I am trying to add labels to SpatialPolygons that would be plotted outside the polygons.
I am using R and the base plot function to stack the layers of my maps.

Here is an example of polygons with labels from the polygonsLabel() function.
(https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.3-5/topics/polygonsLabel)

[image: This is the map I have]

[image: These are the labels I would like to add]

```
#Create polygons 
x1 = c(0, 4, 4, 0, 0)
y1 = c(0, 0, 4, 4, 0)
x2 = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1)
y2 = c(-2, -10, -10, -2, -2)
x3 = c(6, 14, 14, 6, 6)
y3 = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1)
xy.sp = SpatialPolygons(list(
  Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x1,y1))), ID = "test1"), # box
  Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x3,y3))), ID = "test3"), # wide
  Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x2,y2))), ID = "test2")  # high
))

#Plot polygons
plot(xy.sp, col=terrain.colors(3))

#Add labels:
labels=c("Hi!", "A very long text string", "N
a
r
r
o
w")

polygonsLabel(xy.sp, labels, cex=.8,
              col = c('white', 'black', 'maroon'))
```

Comment: The script runs with the  library(rgeos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sf` and `ggsflabel` packages should get you what you want.

Below I've changed your `sp` object to an `sf` (simple features) object, and then added the column for label text.

The `ggsflabel` package info can be found at: https://yutannihilation.github.io/ggsflabel/index.html

You might need to adjust the nudge and force for your plot.

```r
library(rgeos)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> rgeos version: 0.5-3, (SVN revision 634)
#>  GEOS runtime version: 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 
#>  Linking to sp version: 1.4-2 
#>  Polygon checking: TRUE
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)
library(ggsflabel)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggsflabel'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     geom_sf_label, geom_sf_text, StatSfCoordinates

x1 = c(0, 4, 4, 0, 0)
y1 = c(0, 0, 4, 4, 0)
x2 = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1)
y2 = c(-2, -10, -10, -2, -2)
x3 = c(6, 14, 14, 6, 6)
y3 = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1)
xy.sp = SpatialPolygons(list(
  Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x1,y1))), ID = "test1"), # box
  Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x3,y3))), ID = "test3"), # wide
  Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(x2,y2))), ID = "test2")  # high
))

rm(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

#Plot polygons
plot(xy.sp, col=terrain.colors(3))

#Add labels:
labels=c("Hi!", "A very long text string", "N
a
r
r
o
w")

polygonsLabel(xy.sp, labels, cex=.8,
              col = c('white', 'black', 'maroon'))
```

[image]

```
#>          [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 2.001002  1.966994
#> [2,] 9.828784  2.000169
#> [3,] 1.999282 -6.597297


# Change sp object to sf, and add a label column
xy_sf <- st_as_sf(xy.sp)
xy_sf$labels <- labels

ggplot(xy_sf) + 
  geom_sf(fill = c('white', 'black', 'maroon')) + 
  geom_sf_label_repel(aes(label = labels),
                      nudge_y = -3,
                      nudge_x = +2,
                      force = 100)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

*edit:

Label lines from edge:

```
ggplot(xy_sf) + 
  geom_sf_label_repel(aes(label = labels),
                      nudge_y = -3,
                      nudge_x = +2,
                      force = 100) +
  geom_sf(fill = c('white', 'black', 'maroon'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It is very close to what I am looking for. Do you know if it is possible to have the line starting from the edge and not the center? (I will have circle only in my maps see my picture) Would you have any suggestion on a solution that uses the plot function (and not ggplot2)?

Comment: A quick way to do that would be to plot the labels first, and then the polygons.  ggplot2 plots the last layer on top, and would cover up the unwanted part of the line.

Comment: thank you very much! Geom_text_repell from the ggrepel package also allows to indicate the start of the line. I used the first position of the border of each spatialpolygone and it worked.